# How to split string in php into 1800 character chunks or less after new line or if no new line after last word?

Tags: php, regex

Using php I am trying to split a string into chunks of 1800 characters or less, split by the last newline in each 1800 character chunk or if no new line, after the last full word. Below is what I have so far but of course does not work. Only $matches[0] has any content which is the first 1800 characters

`preg_match( "/[\s\S]{1,1800}$/m", $string, $matches );`

Comment: Does it has to be done with preg? And how do you mean last line or last word? Only for the last line or word to split into 1800 chars? Could you please add a sample with smaller length? 1800 chars is a lot of text.

Comment: No it does not have to be done with preg.

What I mean by split by the last new line or last word is within the first 1800 characters of the string, I want it split at the last new line provided there is one (so it may be split at much less than 1800), If there is not a new line within the 1800 characters, I want it split after the last full word within the 1800 characters. Then move on to the next 1800 characters and repeat to the end of the string.

I will work on adding an example in original post.

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~[\s\S]{1,1800}\b(?!\w)~', "\$0\n", $string)`

Comment: Thanks, trying to understand your code, so is its purpose to insure that there is at least one line break every 1800 characters or less after the last full word in such before I try to split it into chunks of 1800 or less? How would I get those chunks into an array as in the code in my question `$matches[0]` has the first chunk after using your code but `$matches[1]` is empty.

Comment: Also, while not sure, from reading your code it seems it may insert a line break even if a line break already exists within 1800 characters? For example, say there is a natural line break at 1775 characters that would be fine to split the string at but your code would insert an additional one closer to 1800 characters right? I don't want to add line breaks if there is at least one already in the first 1800 characters. Regardless, I am still curious how to get the 2nd chunk into `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOT
“…it has great practical value – you can wrap it around you for warmth as you bound across the 
cold moons of Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, 
inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon; use it to sail a mini 
raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in 
hand-to-hand-combat; wrap it round your head 
to ward off noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter
Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes 
that if you can’t see it,
it can’t see you – daft as a bush, but very, very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a 
distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough.”

012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

1. There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable. There is another theory which states that this has already happened.
2. Many were increasingly of        the opinion that they’d all made a big mistake in coming down from the trees in the first place. And some said that even the trees had been a bad move, and that no one should ever have left the oceans.
3. “My doctor says that I have a malformed     public-duty gland and a natural deficiency in moral fibre,” Ford muttered to himself, “and that I am therefore excused from saving Universes.”
4. The ships hung in the sky in much the same way that bricks don’t.
5. “You know,” said Arthur, “it’s at times like this, when I’m trapped in a Vogon airlock with a man from Betelgeuse, and about to die of asphyxiation in deep space that I really wish I’d listened to what my mother told me when I was young.”
“Why, what did she tell you?”
“I don’t know, I didn’t listen.”
6. “Space,” it says, “is big. Really big. You just won’t believe how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it’s a long way down the road to the chemist’s, but that’s just peanuts to space.”
7. “Funny,” he intoned funereally, “how just when you think life can’t possibly get any worse it suddenly does.”
8. Isn’t it enough to see that a garden is beautiful without having to believe that there are fairies at the bottom of it too?
9. A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.
10. Curiously enough, the only thing that went through the mind of the bowl of petunias as it fell was Oh no, not again. Many people have speculated that if we knew exactly why the bowl of petunias had thought that we would know a       lot more about the nature of the Universe than we do now.     
EOT;



$sp = strlen($text);
$ii = 0;
$chars = 179; // 1799
$split = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $sp; $i++) {
    if ($ii == $chars) {
        $char0 = substr($text, $i-$ii, 1);
        if (preg_match("/\s/m", $char0)) { continue; }
        $char3 = substr($text, $i-$ii, $ii);
        if (preg_match("/\s/m", $char3)) {
            for ($iii = $i-1; $iii > 0; $iii--) {
                 $char = substr($text, $iii, 1);
                 if (preg_match("/\s/m", $char)) {
                    if ($iii-1 >= 0) {
                        $char1 = substr($text, $iii-1, 1);
                        if (preg_match("/\s/m", $char1)) { continue; }
                    }
                    $split[] = substr($text, $i-$ii, $ii-($i-$iii));
                    $ii = 0;
                    $i = $iii;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $split[] = $char3;
            $ii = 0;
        }
    }
    $ii++;
}
if ($ii > 0) {
    while (preg_match("/\s/m", substr($text, $i-$ii, 1))) { $i++; }
    $iiii = 0;
    while (preg_match("/\s/m", substr($text, $sp-1-$iiii, 1))) { $iiii++; }
    $split[] = substr($text, $i-$ii, $ii - ($iiii>0?$iiii+1:0));
}

echo hrtime(true), PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

foreach ($split as $index => $part) {
    echo "Length [".$index."]: " . strlen($part) . "\r\n\r\n";
    echo $part . "\r\n\r\n";
}

echo "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

$reg = explode("[xxx]", preg_replace("~[\s\S]{1,".$chars."}\b(?!\w)~", "\$0[xxx]", $text));

echo hrtime(true), PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

foreach ($reg as $index => $part) {
    echo "Length [".$index."]: " . strlen($part) . "\r\n\r\n";
    echo $part . "\r\n\r\n";
}

?>
```

Comparing preg vs my custom made using strpos/substring. I'm still not sure if I understand your goal exactly. The preg doesn't handle 1801 length words without whitespace.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b09a6a3d6a74f7672e82be7f6b785a88ee68f9f0

Comment: Let me try to clarify, I want to take a huge string, within the first 1800 characters I want to grab everything up to the last line break and move on to repeat the process from where left off with the next group of 1800 characters. In cases where there is no line break, I want to grab everything up to the last whole word - including any punctuation like a period after it - I failed to mention that. In your code, much appreciated, I see it does not include a period in the last word (see Length [5]: in 2nd group). Any way to modify it to include periods or other end of sentence punctuation?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see now, you were showing the different ways to iterate over it and the first way includes the period after the word which I wanted while preg_replace way does not.  What causes the number to show up at beginning of both?

Comment: Good "point". ;) replace (?!\w) with (?!\S). But looks bad too. Maybe other regex geeks can help you better. As said maybe a text example would help. Pick one array item and edit it how it should look like.

Comment: I will try the change, thanks, and if needed add an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. `explode()` `$string` into `$parts` based on newlines
2. Then keep adding `$parts` of that to your `$chunk` until it will be bigger then 1800
3. Then add `$chunk` to an array of `$chunks`
4. Repeat until there's no more parts left
5. Use `$chunks` as you wish

Comment: Thanks, but that relies on all of the `$parts` being 1800 characters or less which will not always be the case which is why I mentioned when such occurs it should instead grab up to the last full word within 1800 characters before moving on through the `$string`.